# How to hide a link using php and css

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

I am trying to apply some css in my php for a test to see how to hide a button in my php file. It's not happening at the moment and I am not sure why it is not removing the button.

HTML:

```
<a href="https://test,com" class="button" name="hpy_cs_continue" value="Continue Shopping">Continue Shopping</a>
```

PHP

```
verify_all_products_in_cart() {
    
    $shopping_cart_button = "<style type='text/css'>
                                a[name='hpy_cs_continue']{ 
                                display:none !important;
                                }
                                </style>";
  
    return $shopping_cart_button;
  
}
```

**UPDATE**

The above code is a test code to try and fix the main code below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'verify_all_products_in_cart' );
    
function verify_all_products_in_cart() {
    
    $all_products = false;
    $all_products_array  = wc_get_products( array( 'return' => 'ids', 'limit' => -1 ) );
    $products_in_cart_array = array();
    
  // Loop over $cart items
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {    
    $products_in_cart_array &= in_array($cart_item['product_id']);
}
    if($all_products_array == $products_in_cart_array){
        $all_products = true;
    } else{
        $all_products = false;
    }
                                  
  if ($all_products = true){
      $shopping_cart_button = '<style>a[name="hpy_cs_continue"]{ display:none !important;}</style>';
  } else{
      $shopping_cart_button = '<style>a[name="hpy_cs_continue"]{ display:block !important;}</style>';
  }
   
    return $shopping_cart_button;
  
}
```

Comment: Where is `verify_all_products_in_cart()` called in the context of this php page? Simply returning a string wont automatically include it in your generated html unless you've got some other logic somewhere to actually output it (via an `echo` most likely). That is to say, show us where you call `verify_all_products_in_cart()`

Comment: @WesleySmith Yeah it's just an example code as 'I have a larger piece of code for my woocommerce where I want to hide the link but it doesn't seem to work and my theory is that it's this part of the code that is having the issue. I will include the whole code in update so you can see the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `verify_all_products_in_cart` function, you have several isues:

[in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) needs 2 parameters, you're only sending one

```
$products_in_cart_array &= in_array($cart_item['product_id']);
```

this is doing an assignment `=` not a check `==` / `===`

```
if ($all_products = true){
```

`$all_products` is overused being set in 3 places

`$shopping_cart_button` is a poorly named and unessicary variable with a lot of duplicated code

---

You could re-write this function to something like the below which should work for your needs  (assuming wc_get_products returns an array of ids, if not it may take a bit of modifying):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'verify_all_products_in_cart' );

function verify_all_products_in_cart() {
    $display = 'block';
    $all_products_array  = wc_get_products(['return' => 'ids', 'limit' => -1]); // Im assuming this returns an array of ids for all products..
    $products_in_cart_array = [];
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $products_in_cart_array[]=$cart_item['product_id'];
    }
    if(count($all_products_array) !== count($products_in_cart_array)){
        $display = 'none';
    }
    return "<style>a[name='.'hpy_cs_continue'']{ display:$display !important;}</style>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply apply the CSS directly to the element like that,

```
<a href="https://test,com" style="display: none;" class="button" name="hpy_cs_continue" value="Continue Shopping">Continue Shopping</a>
```